# Why do diode datasheets list a maximum forward current instead of power?

Tags: diodes

Diodes normally list a maximum forward current on their datasheet, for example, the [1N5408 datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/1N5408-Fairchild-datasheet-10635.pdf) states it has a maximum forward current of 3A:

[image: IN5408 Datasheet Absolute Maximum Ratings]

But there's a big difference between say, 3A at 5V (15W), as opposed to 3A at 1000V (3000W).

So why are diode's specified in this way? Does it really mean that this diode would break if I put 5V@5A (25W) through it, but would be fine if I put 1kV@3A (3kW) through it?

Comment: No there is no difference from the forward biassed diode's point of view : its forward voltage is still about `1V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When forward biased (conducting), a diode only knows about the current passing through it.  It doesn't know what the voltage of the circuit is.  The power the diode has to dissipate is its forward voltage times the current - circuit voltage doesn''t come into the calculation at all.

When the diode is reverse biased (not conducting) it does know about the circuit voltage, or rather the reverse voltage that is applied to it.

Answer (score 3):

**Absolute Maximum Ratings** are the "damage ratings" that break the warranty, if these ratings are ever exceeded (even briefly) the part is broken. These limits come from breakdown voltage, thermal limits (melting/vaporizing weak points like bond wires), and any other physical limits of the materials that the device is made of.

**Use the Electrical Characteristics for design limits**.

**At 3A forward current, the forward voltage should be 1.2V**, and the device will be dissipating (1.2V x 3A =) 3.6W of power, which is about half of its rated power dissipation. The package RthetaJA is 20 degrees C per Watt, so 3.6W power dissipation inside the junction leads to a temperature rise of 72 degrees C above ambient, so about 97 C at the outside of the case. Note that if ambient temperature is more than about 60 C then you have to reduce the forward current, see figure 1 Forward Current Derating Curve.

If you somehow put 5A through this diode (violating its Abs Max limits), it would break -- though it's not always immediately obvious that a part is damaged. For more complicated devices, the damage can manifest as out-of-sepc drift, offset/gain errors, or even logic errors. More complicated parts have more places where damage can hide. With a single diode junction, when it breaks, it will be pretty obvious.

If you biased the part at -1000V (**reverse biased** instead of forward biased of course), the reverse current would be near 0 because that's how diodes work. The Electrical Characteristics table shows the rated reverse current of 5.0uA at ambient temperature, or 500uA when hot (100C). You can see in figure 4 how much they guard-banded the -1000V rating, the reverse current is near zero until the bias voltage is about 120% of rating, so at -1200V the junction breaks down and a large current flows. Note the Thermal Characteristics: only 6.25W is allowed for power dissipation, and at -1200V that's 5mA.